# Regex for trimming whitesprace around tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently removing the space between HTML tags with `.replace(/>\s+</g,'><')`.

This will replace:

```
<hello> a b c </hello> <world> x y z </world>
```

with:

```
<hello> a b c </hello><world> x y z </world>
```

I would like to update this function to achieve the following result:

```
<hello>a b c</hello><world>x y z</world>
```

How would I rephrase this regex to also strip the new lines, spaces, and tabs that surround inner tag content?

Comment: In general you can't handle arbitrary HTML with regular expressions. In very constrained situations it may be possible, like if you know that the targeted HTML always fits within some rigid forms.

Comment: @Pointy it seems like I should be safe as long as I avoid `<` &  `>` opting for `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: `.replace(/(>)\s+|\s+(<)/g, "$1$2")`

Comment: ^ That seems like an answer, not a comment to me.

Comment: You're doing something wrong if you must remove spaces before XML tags. What do you want with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"<hello> a b c </hello> <world> x y z </world>".replace(/\s*(<\/?.*?\/?>)\s*/g, "$1")
```

Prints:

```
"<hello>a b c</hello><world>x y z</world>"
```

Explanation:

`\s*` - 0 or n spaces before the tag

`(<\/?.*?\/?>)` - tag, `<...>`, `</...>` or `<.../>`, captured

`\s*` - 0 or n spaces after the tag

The captured tag is put back into the string minus matched spaces that were not captured

Answer (score 1):

replace it with two steps

code sample:

```
x = `<hello> 
a b c </hello> <world>
 x y z 
 </world>`;
x = x.replace(/>\s*/g, '>');
x = x.replace(/\s*</g, '<');
console.log(x);
```

output:

```
<hello>a b c</hello><world>x y z</world>
```